# Neural networks in python

Tags: python

How do I write code for asking for the data set from the user in python? (I'm trying to code a generalised neural network from scratch. So number of layers and activations are to be input from the user. And it needs to be an object oriented approach. I'm having trouble connecting things

Comment: I think your question is currently too broad for StackOverflow. I suggest that you start developing/coding and come back with specific questions when your code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be more specific about what kind of data you want to feed. What this network is going to do? For example in case of a binary image classification input would be consisted of images splitted into train/test set with proper label data. This can be provided via various data structures, you can ask for a dataframe filled with loaded images and labels. However more efficient would be loading data into numpy arrays.